# Extract multiple css files to different directories

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I'm trying to compile some sass files and extract each one to multiple paths.

Example:

`resources/home/a.scss -> public/home/a.css`

`resources/home/layout/b.scss -> public/home/layout/b.scss`

`resources/login/c.scss -> public/login/c.css`

At the moment I'm using this config and it bundles every scss file:

```
const path = require("path")
const webpack = require("webpack")
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
// Context is an absolute path to the directory where webpack will be
// looking for our entry points.
context: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'resources/assets'),

entry: 
     [
       './sass/app/home/a.scss',
       './sass/app/home/layout/b.scss',
       './sass/app/login/c.scss',
    ],
output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: '[name].js'
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(scss)$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
        }

    ]
},
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: '[name].css', allChunks: true })
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you are using an `Array` as the `entry`, which means that all of the dependencies (in this case the different css files, are added into the same output file).

You should change it to:

```
entry: {
 a:  './sass/app/home/a.scss',
 b:  './sass/app/home/layout/b.scss',
 c:  './sass/app/login/c.scss'
}
```

You can read more here https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#object-syntax